# Build C executable for Raspberry Pi on Windows or Linux

Tags: c, eclipse, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, eclipse-cdt

I have to design a C executable (no GUI) that is supposed to run on Raspberry PI. I'm familiar with design using IDE like Visual Studio or Eclipse (with CDT plugin). If i use Raspberry PI as a design machine, I think I have no chance to use a standard IDE. I should use makefiles and gcc compiler only.

Is there any chance to develop Raspberry PI executable using Visual Studio (for Windows) or Eclipse (for both Windows and Linux).

Comment: If the executable does not do anything specific to the Raspberry (I/O or similar) you can just develop it on the same distribution running on your normal computer in a virtual environment.  Then you should be able to recompile it again on the Raspberry so it will run there.

Comment: Check the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162072/installing-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler

Comment: I'd suggest to go for Linux this time around. On Windows you will have to deal with Cygwin which isn't always the easiest way to go. Linux will free you from a lot of RPi pains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify to eclipse projects with Makefiles. You can also specify a compilation toolchain.

So yes, you can develop and compile for Raspberry Pi or for other plateforms using Eclipse.

For getting toolchain and other tools for Rasp Pi you can find things [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi).

In Eclipse, you create a new or import a project choosing **Makefile Project with Existing Code** then add your toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a newer Pi like the 4, you should be able to run eclipse directly from the Pi desktop.  You can download via:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

This will be a stripped-down version and will likely run quite slow, so I agree compiling on a more powerful remote machine is better...

> Is there any chance to develop Raspberry PI executable using Visual Studio (for Windows) or Eclipse (for both Windows and Linux).

Yes, this is called cross-compiling. You can set up a cross-compile toolchain for the raspberry pi on windows or linux and configure your Eclipse CDT project to build with the toolchain.  You can even set up remote debugging.

[This website](https://www.gurucoding.com/rpi_cross_compiler/2020/01_introduction/) has good information and a step-by-step guide for windows using cygwin.

[This](https://medium.com/@eternalamit5/raspberry-pi-development-setup-on-eclipse-linux-and-debugging-via-ssh-a1927852e3a2) looks like a good guide for linux.

Edit:
Just realized you asked for Visual Studio on Windows.  I don't think there is Visual Studio support for this.  The example I pointed to sets up cygwin so you have an emulated linux environment.  You could also set up a VM using free VM software and install a linux environment that way, and run eclipse CDT from there.  This is what I did when setting up a cross compiling environment for the Raspi.