# Source code of any version of linux operating system

Tags: operating-system, raspberry-pi

I am working on my operating system project, which is indeed very hard for me. My university ask for modifications in any of the raspberry pi operating system. I have tried surfing the net and did not found anything. I have taken the lectures provided by Cambridge university.

http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/

Thanx to them now I know a little about kernel.

But I want to create a complete operating system atleast which could behave like a terminal but could support keyboard , screen internet

Answer (score 0):

I have founded a way to get the source of an operating system plus to cross compile it on Linux.

[Installing Raspberry Pi Cross-Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162072/installing-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler)

I hope you will also find it helpful.