# cross compiler raspberry pi incomplete type while native compiler works

Tags: c++, cross-compiling

I've set up a cross compiler for my raspberry pi, the one I found here: [Installing Raspberry Pi Cross-Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162072/installing-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler)

Now this has been working fine, up to the point where I want to use an I2c library (i2c-dev.h).

When compiling the code below with the arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ compiler, I get an error:

```
In file included from src/I2c.cpp:8:0:
src/../Include/I2c.h:29:18: error: field ‘message’ has incomplete type
   struct i2c_msg message;
                  ^
```

Meanwhile, when I compile the code on a raspi, it simply runs.

```
#ifndef I2C_H_
#define I2C_H_

#include <linux/i2c-dev.h> // Defines i2c_msg
#include ...

using namespace std;


typedef struct {
    struct i2c_msg message;

    void (*callback)(int);
    int messageID;

} t_msgQueue;
```

Any ideas on a possible cause, or a solution on how I can make the cross compiler work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by adding a

```
#include <linux/i2c.h>
```

before the i2c-dev headers. Still no idea why the two compilers gave different results...

Answer (score 0):

My first suspect would be differing GCC versions between the RPi and your cross compiler; GCC has been known to change how it processes #include statements over time.

Barring a version difference, check to ensure that a host include file hasn't been picked up somwhere by accident.

Comment: I've checked the compiler versions:
- cross compiler is GNU 4.8.3
- native compiler is GNU 4.9.4
The release notes however, do not discuss any changes regarding handling of #includes or structs.
Furthermore, the header files used are identical.
Any other ideas?