# How do I configure gcc to search for crt1.o and other libc files in a specific location?

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, libc, toolchain, crosstool-ng

I'm trying to build a cross-compilation toolchain for Raspberry Pi using Crosstool-NG. And I have already done this. But when I try to use my toolchain with rootfs from Raspberry Pi using the `--sysroot` option (as it said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162072/installing-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/19269715#19269715)) I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/features.h:364:25: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
```

The problem is that this header on Raspberry Pi device is located in `/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf`, not in just `/usr/include` directory. I can add this directory to the list of include directories using `-I` flag, but then I get the following error:

```
/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
```

The problem is similar: the `libm` library is located in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`, not in just `/usr/lib/` directory. Of course I can use `-L` flag to solve this problem, but anyway I get the following error:

```
/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
```

The reason is the same: `crt1.o` is located in the `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` directory. And there is no flags to solve this problem. My compiler is configured to search for `crt1.o` in the `/usr/lib/` directory. And I had to create symbolic links in the `/usr/lib` to `crt` files in `arm-linux-gnueabihf` subdirectory to workaround this problem.

Thus all libc files are located in a non-standard location. `crt1.o` on my Ubuntu is also located in a non-standard location, it's located in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`. It seems many toolchains use this behaviour therefore I guess this is some standard feature of *gcc*.

So the question: is there any option to compile *gcc* to make it search for headers, libraries and `crt1.o` in some specific location? Ho do I configure my toolchain to place all *libc* files into `arm-linux-gnueabihf` subdirectory? I guess there should be some gcc *configure* option for doing this. But which one?