# How to link libraries on Raspberry Pi cross compiler?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I followed [this guide](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/05/06/building-gcc-cross-compiler-raspberry-pi/) to build a cross compiler for Raspberry Pi ARMv7. It works fine (compiles ok hello world) but the problem is I can't use Raspberry Pi libraries such as wiringpi, sqlite etc.

This is my Makefile.

```
CC = /opt/cross-pi-gcc/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
QUOTE := "
CFLAGS = -g -lwiringPi -pthread -lpthread
PROGRAM = lora
OBJDIR = obj

CPP_SRCS += \
src/main.cpp \
src/radio/sx1276/sx1276.cpp \
src/radio/radio.cpp \

OBJ_FILES += \
$(OBJDIR)/main.o \
$(OBJDIR)/sx1276.o \
$(OBJDIR)/radio.o \


all: make_dir $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $(OBJ_FILES) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROGRAM)  

make_dir:
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/main.o: src/main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJDIR)/service.o: src/service/service.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJDIR)/sx1276.o: src/radio/sx1276/sx1276.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJDIR)/radio.o: src/radio/radio.cpp 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm $(PROGRAM)
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
/opt/cross-pi-gcc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lwiringPi
```

I copied some libraries from my Pi into a folder on my home dir with this command.

```
rsync -vR --progress -rl --delete-after --safe-links pi@192.168.1.PI:/{lib,usr,opt/vc/lib} $HOME/raspberrypi/rootfs
```

Which I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162072/how-to-install-the-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler-on-my-linux-host-machine/58559140#58559140).

But I'm not sure how to link them. Did I overlook something?

Note: The piece of code I'm trying to compile was compiling fine on Windows's cross-compiler.
I'm trying to setup a tool-chain on my Linux desktop. I'm using Manjaro.

Comment: You could replace all those compile rules for individual files with a single pattern rule, together with your CPP_SRCS variable.  Normally you preserve the directory structure, e.g. src/service/service.cpp -> obj/service/service.o and this will help you generate OBJ_FILES automatically from CPP_SRCS and have a generic rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the linker where to look for the libraries.
You can add the flag `-L$HOME/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/lib`, or wherever `libwiringPi.so` is located.

You have to point the compiler to the right headers as well. For that you use the `-I` flag. E.g. `-I$HOME/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/include`. This goes in the `CFLAGS` of the targets that include `wiringPi.h`.

Also, `-lwiringPi -pthread -lpthread` don't belong in the `CFLAGS`, they are linker flags. You only need them in the target that builds `PROGRAM`. You could add a separate variable `LDFLAGS`, for example.

Comment: I added the full path of -L/home/name/raspberrypi/rootfs at the end of the CFLAGS. I still get the same error

Comment: @MrBit you have to use the full path to where libwiringPi.so is located.

Comment: I replaced `-lwiringPi` `-pthread` `-lpthread` with the `-L$HOME/raspberrypi/rootfs` path but I'm getting `undefined reference to` the functions

Comment: @MrBit don't replace it, add the `-L` flag. Keep the other flags.

Comment: I added the full path `-L/home/username/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/lib/` at the end, it gives me `fatal error: wiringPi.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: You have to do the same for the include paths. See my edit.

Comment: @MrBit: Are you adjusting the link rule or the compile rules?  The linker doesn't need a header file and the compiler doesn't need libraries!

Comment: @tttapa: Since he was completing the compile step before and failing on the link step, I don't think he needs to mess with the include path any further.

Comment: yes I had to add the `-I` flag. Also, from what you said my Makefile is a little messy. I'll see if I can do something better. Thank you very much for your help!