# Raspberry PI Cross Compiling QT GUI Application in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, raspbian

I typically write Linux and QNX command-line applications in VIM, generally steer away from graphical IDEs. I am currently working on a simple GUI-based application for the RPI that presents a text field for entering commands, and a read-only text field for displaying logging statements.

Is there a de facto standard means of setting up a build environment in Linux (ie: Ubuntu) so I can compile for ARM on the RPI and just deploy the binaries via NFS/SSH?

Additionally, is there a standard means of creating a staging area (ie: a bare-bones empty QT project with a makefile in place that already knows that the only valid target is to use the x86 compiler targeted for ARM)?

The end goal is to set up a few virtual machines with a bunch of empty/blank sample projects that will just build via the command-line when executing `make`.

I have read through other similar questions I found on SO, but they deal solely with installing the compiler. I also need to figure out how to set up a sample makefile project.

Thank you.

---

**References**

1. [Cross-Compiling for RaspBerry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214563/cross-compiling-for-raspberry-pi)
2. [Cross-compilation for Raspberry Pi in GCC. Where to start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973020/cross-compilation-for-raspberry-pi-in-gcc-where-to-start?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in an answer to a similar question of yours.

[Cross compiling for Raspberry PI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713267/cross-compiling-for-raspberry-pi)

As for a staging area, no. You just need to cleverly write your makefiles so you don't clobber your existing OS installation.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to link your QT4 application source (written on the PC) with QT4 libraries  (on the RPi) compiled for Raspberry Pi/Raspbian OS.

To summarize:

1. Install the RPi's cross compiling toolchain on your PC.
2. Install the QT4 libraries on the Raspberry Pi/Raspbian OS.
3. Mount the RPi's root file system onto your PC.
4. Write a makefile that uses the RPi's cross compiling   toolchain to build the QT source and link it to the ARM11 / Raspbian specific QT4 libraries (available on the mounted RPi filesystem) to create an ARM11/Raspbian binary.

The makefile must also use the moc-qt4 tool to generate necessary boilerplate code...one .moc.cpp for every .h header file containing a QT class declaration.

For a more detailed procedure : http://hertaville.com/2014/04/12/cross-compiling-qt4-app/